# Google Cloud SQL - Not supported external master gtid_mode: 'OFF'. Please make sure gtid_mode is set to 'ON'

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to start a Google Cloud SQL instance using the Migration option.

I've followed the instructions from the documentation and made a backup with this instructions:

```
mysqldump --databases mydb -h 1.1.1.1 -u user -p \
--hex-blob --skip-triggers --set-gtid-purged=OFF \
--default-character-set=utf8 --single-transaction=TRUE > backup.sql
```

Uploaded this file to cloud storage and started the wizard to migrate.

After a while starting the instance, this error occured:

```
Not supported external master gtid_mode: 'OFF'. Please make sure gtid_mode is set to 'ON'.
```

After some research I think I need to configure the replica instance to use **gtid-mode=ON**. And it could be configured on my.cnf or using the command below

```
SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_MODE = ON;
```

The problem is that I don't know how to make this configuration, because the instance is not up, and I can't connect it to a compute instance to run the commands.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to insert this command: `SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_MODE = ON;` on the begin of your backup file?

You could use `sed -i '1s;^;SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_MODE = ON;\n;' backup.sql` to prepend this command on your backup file

Comment: Your command didn't work for my, but this one worked: `sed -i '1 i\SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_MODE = ON;' backup.sql`

Comment: Didn't work... I've tried to run this command directly in the db, and its not possible because gtid_mode is readonly. It should be set on my.cnf and restart server.

Now I'm trying to run mysqldump without `--set-gtid-purged=OFF`

Comment: Tried to run mysqldump without `--set-gtid-purged=OFF`, didn't work too.

4 de abr de 2019 19:20:18
Create replica
Not supported external master gtid_mode: 'OFF'. Please make sure gtid_mode is set to 'ON'.